# Any Libraries or Examples of Natural Language Generation in C#?

Tags: c#, nlp

Can anyone recommend any examples or libraries to aid natural language generation in C#?

I want to take description of objects in XML and generate human readable descriptions.

I have found libraries such as SharpNLP, but they are aimed at processing not generating text.

__

I have found the SimpleNLG library for Java, which I will use unless anyone can reccommend a native .Net library http://code.google.com/p/simplenlg/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a C# port of SimpleNLG now: https://github.com/nickhodge/SharpSimpleNLG

Answer (score 1):

Unless someone else can add something, it looks like the only library for .net would be to create a wrapper around SimpleNLG (they comment on this in their documentation).

For my solution, I found it easier to just use some fairly simple code to describe text using spinning and merging sentences.